# How to check that any of the channel in spring-integration SI flow is in processing state?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

Hi Artem / Gary/ Friends,

There is a requirement where I need to deploy my ear on application server on PROD. The solution flow starts with JMS Message Listener in SI flow and the whole framework is SI based, where we have used delayer aggregator JDBC outbound adapter. 
Now before deployment I need to know that there is no live thread active in SI flow ( means processing has been completed by all the channel and there is no live message in between ) so that I can begin the deployment of EAR on my application server.
As I have used control bus to stop the message listener but I also need to know that the message processing has been completed to end and no live SI message exists in the flow.

Can you please help.

Thanks 
Ram

Answer (score 0):

Well, actually I'm not sure why you worry about that. Any re-deploy causes the application stop and resources disposal, therefore, no more any thread activity after that.

Although you can consider to use [`SmartLifecycleRoleController`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#endpoint-roles) for the purpose like assign for all critical endpoints the same `role` and invoke its `stopLifecyclesInRole()` when you need.

From other side the endpoint `stop` means that it won't consume any new messages from the `channel` (or source system like JMS). Right any long-running Thread will be still active and may be even with some process around the message. AFAIK the container tries to finalize all the active threads for the application and eventually just interrupts if otherwise. For this case you definitely should ensure some transactional / anknowlage rejection semantics for critical data. Therefore any unfinished process will just end up with rallback/nack state for the message. And a new instance of your application will be able to start over for that message again.

I don't have any answer for you regarding some hook to check thread activity at run time. But I wonder if you will be able to figure out something like `claim-check` to wait until `sending` part is equal to `processed` after the JMS Inbound Endpoint stop.